# Replace formulas with resulting values in excel using VBScrip

Tags: excel, vbscript

Am trying to replace all the formulas in an excel spreadsheet while keeping everything else unchanged. Managed to do it using VBA but can't find a way using Vbscript.

Usage of macros is not an option as they are disabled by default and the goal is to update the excel file without human intervention.

This is the code I tried (latest attempt), it copies the results from the formulas as values but nothing else from the original sheet is taken (lose all graphic objects and formatting).

```
function create_daily_dash()
    dim i
    dim current_sheet
    outputFiletype = 51 'type_xlsx

    inputFilename = myExcelFile
    outputFilename = path & newfilename

    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set currentWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(inputFilename)
    Set newWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add()

    i = 0
    For Each current_sheet In currentWorkbook.Worksheets
        If current_sheet.Visible Then 
            i = i + 1

            Dim new_sheet
            If newWorkbook.Sheets.Count < i Then
                newWorkbook.Sheets.Add , newWorkbook.Sheets(i-1)
            End If
            Set new_sheet = newWorkbook.Sheets(i)
            new_sheet.Name = current_sheet.Name

            current_sheet.UsedRange.Copy
            new_sheet.Select
            new_sheet.UsedRange.PasteSpecial -4163
        End If
    Next
    newWorkbook.SaveAs outputFilename, outputFiletype
    currentWorkbook.Close False
    newWorkbook.Close False
    objExcel.Quit
end function
```

Comment: What about "Copy"/"Paste as Value"?

Comment: Can you post the VBScript you have so far?

Comment: Updated the original post with code

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get a way to replace the formulas with the corresponding values but it does it extremely slowly.

It' just a loop that goes through the interval of cells I want to update and replaces the formula with the value one cell at a time.

Am sure there's a better way to do this but can't find anything.
This is the code I'm using:

```
for i=1 to ColNo 
    for j=1 to RowNo
        curr_sheet.Cells(i,j).value = curr_sheet.Cells(i,j).value
    next
next
```

Any tips on how to get the same result more efficiently are very welcome.